# Flutter DateTimePicker: Disable sunday from weekdays not working

Tags: flutter, dart, datetimepicker

I'm **trying to set Sunday not selectable** from DateTimePicker in flutter. Somehow it works for the other 6 days except Sunday.

```dart
List<int> weekdays = [0,2,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1];

// ...

DateTimePicker(
  selectableDayPredicate: (DateTime val) => val.weekday == weekdays[0] || val.weekday == weekdays[1] || val.weekday == weekdays[2] || val.weekday == weekdays[3] || val.weekday == weekdays[4] || val.weekday == weekdays[5] || val.weekday == weekdays[6] ? false : true,
  initialValue: DateTime.now().toString(),
  initialDate: DateTime.now(),
  firstDate: DateTime.now(),
  dateLabelText: 'Date',
  type: DateTimePickerType.date,
  lastDate: DateTime.now().add(const Duration(days: 15)),
  onChanged: (date) {
    //
  },
  validator: (date) {
    return null;
  },
),
```

Output Screenshot: https://prnt.sc/U73nGkLjqZMZ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Am I understood correctly that you want to make only Sundays not selectable of the calendar?

If correct, you can try:

```dart
DateTimePicker(
  selectableDayPredicate: (DateTime dateTime) => dateTime.weekday != DateTime.sunday,
  // other parameters...
)
```

then all Sundays will be NOT selectable.

### Edit

I got your meaning, sorry for confusing.
You may want to try this one:

```dart
  final List<int> disableWeekdays = [
    DateTime.sunday,
    DateTime.tuesday,
    // any weekdays you want to make disabled...
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DateTimePicker(
      selectableDayPredicate: (DateTime dateTime) => !disableWeekdays.contains(dateTime.weekday),
      // other parameters...
    );
  }
```

Comment: Not only Sunday. It can be any other day. It will depend on the List 'weekdays'. If you check the screenshot I attached, it disabled Tuesday but not Sunday. but according to my code, it supposed to disable Sunday too.

Comment: You want to make weekdays enable/disable depending on list values, right? What does the integers `-1`, `0`, and `2` in the list mean?

Comment: @Office1 `-1` is for enabled, and others are weekday indices to make disabled?

Comment: 0 means disable Sunday, 2 means disable Tuesday, and -1 won't disable any day. I have solved this issue with some modification. => (val.weekday == DateTime.sunday && weekdays.contains(0)) || //other condition.. thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: @Office1 I got it, and updated the answer. You may get better readability with new solution, thanks, enjoy your code :D.